# Keras: Predict a combination of categorical and continuous variables

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

The output I am trying to predict with my keras model contains a mixture of continuous and categorical variables. How do I design the architecture to simultaneously predict continuous and categorical outputs?

If all the output variables were continuous then I would use a [regression loss](https://keras.io/api/losses/regression_losses) with a linear activation on the final layer, while for binary/categorical outputs I would use [probabilistic loss](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses) with sigmoid/softmax loss on the final layer. But my dataset requires a prediction of both a continuous value *and* the category each sample belongs to.

It is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67977797/how-can-you-predict-a-combination-of-categorical-and-continuous-variables-with-s) but for Keras/Tensorflow. Most questions on this topic deal with mixtures of categorical/continuous on the *input* side, not the *output* side.

Six sample **outputs** I'm trying to predict are shown in the example table below. The first column is a continuous variables (which will be normalized first) while the second column is categorical.

| VarA | VarB |
| --- | --- |
| 45.2 | ABC |
| 81.7 | ABC |
| 90.6 | REK |
| 72.1 | REK |
| 1.6 | BIJ |
| 34.3 | BIJ |

My intuition is to consider two alternative solutions:

1. Ignore the fact that column B is categorical (or binary once hot-encoded) and use [regression loss](https://keras.io/api/losses/regression_losses) when fitting.
2. Create a [multi-output graph](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/) with a structure similar to:
   `model = keras.Model(inputs=input_array, outputs=[output_continuous, output_categorical])` so that a regression and CategoricalCrossentropy loss can be used at the same time.

Is there a generally accepted best approach for solving this type of problem?

Comment: To my best knowledge this requires two separate models, since with Keras' functional API, you can model two outputs, but will have one common loss in the model https://github.com/Bixi81/Python-ml/blob/master/keras_multitarget_functionalAPI.py

Comment: I have to correct myself: it is possible to use multiple losses https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404309/how-does-keras-handle-multiple-losses

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10306